# The given role or permission should use guard `web, api` instead of `admin`

Tags: php, laravel

First, I registered as a standard member. There is no role definition. Then from the panel I created. I created a new user page. Here I want to create a new user and set the role to this user. Although everything is ok I get the "**Spatie\Permission\Exceptions\GuardDoesNotMatch The given role or permission should use guard `web, api` instead of `admin`.**" error.

I use another package, the passport module, in the software. I don't know if it has an effect.

Firstly my User model as below

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasRoles, HasApiTokens, Notifiable;


    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

UserController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\User;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use RealRashid\SweetAlert\Facades\Alert;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\DataTables\UsersDataTable;
use Datatables;
use Session;
use DB;
use Auth;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    // use RegistersUsers;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware(['auth', 'isAdmin']);
        //isAdmin middleware lets only users with a //specific permission permission to access these resources
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $roles = Role::all();
        return view('panel.users.create')->with(compact('roles'));
    }

    public function register(Request $data)
    {
        try {

            DB::beginTransaction();

            $validatedData = $data->validate([
                'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
                'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
                'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:6', 'confirmed'],
                'roles' => ['required'],
            ]);

            $user = new User;
            $user->name = $data->name;
            $user->email = $data->email;
            $user->password = Hash::make($data['password']);
            $user->save();

            $roles = $data['roles'];
            $role_r = Role::where('id', '=', $roles)->firstOrFail();
            $user->assignRole($role_r);

            DB::commit();
            return redirect()->route('user.list')->withErrors($validatedData)->with('toast_success','New User Added');
        }

            catch (Exception $e) {
                try {
                    DB::rollBack();
                }
                catch (Exception $e) {
                }
                return response([
                    'error' => true,
                    'message' => $e->getMessage() . $e->getLine()
                ]);
            }
    }



    public function list(UsersDataTable $dataTable)
    {
        return $dataTable->render('panel.users.list');
    }

}
```

AdminMiddleware

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\User;

class AdminMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = User::all()->count();
        if (!($user == 1)) {
            if (!Auth::user()->hasPermissionTo('Administer roles & permissions'))
            //If user does //not have this permission
        {
                abort('401');
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

config/auth.php

```
<?php

return [

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],

    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

I searched on the internet but I couldn't find a solution. Where do you think I am doing wrong or wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, You have to define "admin" role in config/auth.php as following:

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admin',
    ]
],
```

Next, you have to make 2 model for normal user and admin as following:

```
class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
    // this code will define user's guard   
    protected $guard = 'admin';

    // rest of code
}

class User extends Authenticatable
{    
    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
    // rest of code
}
```

Finally, you have to use these 2 models when user login as following:

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{   
    protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $user = \App\Models\User::where([
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => (md5($request->password))
        ])->first();

        if ($user) {
            $this->guard()->login($user, $request->has('remember'));

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}

class AdminLoginController extends Controller
{    
    protected function guard(){
        return Auth::guard('admin');
    }

    protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $user = \App\Models\Admin::where([
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => md5($request->password)
        ])->first();

        if ($user) {
            $this->guard()->login($user, $request->has('remember'));

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest:admin')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

That's all. Hope to help

Comment: Wow, great answer with full example code. it saved my time... thanks...